# Disable touch screen while using scrcpy

Tags: adb, touchscreen, scrcpy

I have a broken-screen, non-rooted Xiaomi Redmi Note 6 Pro that looks like this

[image]

and I'm experiencing a LOT of ghost touches (and the digitizer's gone).

I am using `scrcpy` to control it from my PC, so I want to disable the touchscreen because otherwise it interferes with my commands and does what it wants.

I don't want to detach the digitizer physically since I have no tools for opening my mobile and this one has to be opened from the screen, so I could damage it more.

How can I do it (possibly with ADB)?

Comment: `scrcpy --turn-screen-off`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I fixed it the way it was suggested me by @rom1v `scrcpy --turn-screen-off` and works better than what I was expecting!

Comment: Coming back later, this works for the Note 9 Pro as well. Just make sure it is unlocked when you run the command and don't touch it afterwards.