# How to disable the ghost touch and use device with mouse in android 4.0.4

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, touchscreen

Got an android tablet iBall i6012 with ghost touch. Its screen is touching in keyboard area with some fungus between touch screen and LCD. This is an hardware issue, have around 7 touch area in screen touching every second. want to use the tablet with USB mouse. Tried Touch Lock by kidscrape. It is locking the screen completely including mouse input.

Looking for a touch input blocking solution with mouse input support in Android 4.0.4

Comment: related https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224255

Comment: @alecxs solution mentioned in related link requires scrcpy, with minimum os Android 5+. iBall i6012 is Android 4.0.4 cannot use scrcpy.

Comment: maybe someone can have a look into source code and tell you which adb command is executed from --turn-screen-off

Comment: @alecxs scrcpy didn't use ADB to turn off the screen, it used [Android code `SurfaceControl`, interfacing with the device](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/commit/12a3bb25d39037931f577dc0165b3e517aad92df#diff-a95a5041663905668300cc4475696ff0816fbd9f321e18fe99ce9497b8914008R163)